# How to eliminate specific character with regex java

Tags: java, regex

Need to count number of syllables in given text.
Every contiguous sequence of one or more vowels, **except for a lone “e” at the end of a word if the word has another vowel or set of contiguous vowels**, makes up one syllable(Consider "y" as vowel)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count =0;
    String text    = "This is a test.  How many???  Senteeeeeeeeeences are here... there should be 5!  Right?";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[Ee]+(?!\\b)|[aiouyAIOUY]+");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Output of above program is *15*
It needs to be **16**
It should to eliminate count of e's when it is last character in a word not containing any vowel i.e.., It should not eliminate count of e's in word(be)
**How to specify that condition in Pattern**

Comment: If I run your code the output is `15`. You expect to have `15`. So what's the problem?

Comment: I think the expected result should be 16.

Comment: @Fredo Than it make more sense.

Comment: Not directly related but the regex could be simplified by using the _case insensitive_ flag for Pattern: `Pattern.compile("[e]+(?!\\b)|[aiouy]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
"(\\b[^aiouyeEAIOUY]+[Ee]\\b)|([aiouyAIOUY]\\b)|([aiouyeAIOUYE]{2,}\\b)|([aiouyeAIOUYE]+(?!\\b))"
```

Adn with the purpose of driu:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\b[^aiouye]+e\\b)|([aiouy]\\b)|([aiouye]{2,}\\b)|([aiouye]+(?!\\b))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I observe 4 scenarios to count (I group the 4 parts to better debug):

1. An **e** is at end and there are no other vowel in the word
2. One vowel (except **e**) is at end of the word
3. Two or more vowels (including **e**) are at end of the word
4. One or more vowels (including **e**) are in the word but not at the end

Comment: Works fine but problem is for words like **serIEs** it should count  **IE** as single @fredo

Comment: can u explain your solution

Answer (score 0):

**Correct Solution**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count =0;
    //String text    = "Here is a series of test sentences. Your program should find 3 sentences, 33 words, and 49 syllables. Not every word will have the correct amount of syllables (example, for example), but most of them will.";
    String text = "series";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("e(?!$)[aeiouy]*|[aieyou]*e(?!$)|[ayiou]+|\\b[^aiouye]+[e]\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tried with this string: `heitahore Suries e aei baoeifife bce Seraie Seirio` I think that's not ok for h**ei**tahore.

Comment: Nope... take this word: haeitahore.
The first part will find **e** at end even the word contains vowels